# Do i need to learn c before learning c++?

Tags: c++, c, arduino

I started to learn C, but I realized that all i could do was to build thse console programs (correct me if i'm wrong). So, i've seen that c++ is much more "graphic", like, you can build apps and windows, and is also OOP, what makes everything easier. So, do I need to finish learning c before c++?

Also, what interested me about C was that I could program an Arduino. Can I program an Arduino with C++?

Comment: C++ has **nothing** to do with graphics. You can just as easily build graphical applications in C (see Win32's GDI+, GTK, etc. etc.)

Comment: The majority of the Win32 API, portions of which are used for creating GUIs on Windows, is designed primarily for C, but can also be used in other languages that are compatible with C, including C++.  So, more generically, the ability to create GUIs depends on the platform API used by your code, not the language that your code is written in.

Comment: And yes, you can use C++ to program an Arduino.

Comment: C++ doesn't have any "graphic" capabilities in the standard library either.

Comment: You can do it in C and it is simpler, lots of good people give up on programming when they try to learn C++ . If you are having problems with C then C++ is not your solution.

Answer (score 2):

All the "graphic" things are supported by libraries, no matter in C(e.g. GTK, SDL) or C++ (e.g. QT).

And for hardware drive programming, no matter what language it is. You have to compile it into binaries so that the hardware will knows how to run. You can even create your own language if you can write your own compiler.